# Facebook FQL Query only returning a limited amount of objects?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am running an FQL query through the Facebook api:

```
SELECT username FROM page WHERE CONTAINS("Musician/Band")
```

I am expecting this to return a large amount of items, but it only returned about 100.  Is there a limit on the amount of items a query like this will return?  Or is this just not a query that is written wrong?  In case you couldn't tell, I wanted the usernames of all of the musical artists on FB.

Thank you for your insight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FQL has `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` keywords. You can get upto 5000 results at a time but better way to do it is through pagination

eg:

```
SELECT username FROM page WHERE CONTAINS("Musician/Band") LIMIT 200 //gets first 200 results
SELECT username FROM page WHERE CONTAINS("Musician/Band") LIMIT 200 OFFSET 201 //to get next 200 results
```

and so on..

Also you can use [Facebook multiquery](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/fql/#multi) to minimize number of queries made.